# pyBarcode code39 adds random digit

Tags: python

I am creating a .png barcode from an alpha numerical value. I am using Python and the pyBarcode module. The problem is that, when I use code39, it adds a random digit to the end. Other barcode formats I tested seems to give the same problem.

Here is my code snippet

```
unique_filename = uuid.uuid4()
barcode_writer = ImageWriter()
ean = barcode.get('code39', "Testing-One-two-1-2",barcode_writer)
filename = ean.save(BARCODE_DIR +str(unique_filename))
```

And the created .png:

**Non-OP Edit:** Link to image is now broken.

Hope someone can assist me.
Thanks

Comment: Is it possible that the additional digit you are seeing is a checksum?

Comment: The link to your image no longer works. Please post it again, and I can embed it in the post for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the source code for pyBarcode [init function](https://bitbucket.org/benhodgson/pybarcode/src/58a37624ed5f6b4aaca15f0520047e095c735866/barcode/__init__.py?at=default) on line 57 the barcode.get() function calls:

```
return barcode(code, writer)
```

So it creates a barcode with the parameters `code` and `writer` set.

In the [codex.py](https://bitbucket.org/benhodgson/pybarcode/src/58a37624ed5f6b4aaca15f0520047e095c735866/barcode/codex.py?at=default) file on line 52, the code39 class is created with the checksum parameter True by default:

```
def __init__(self, code, writer=None, add_checksum=True):
```

And as per lnmx you have to explicitly set the checksum off if you don't want it.

Answer (score 3):

I tried using the parameter 'add_checksum=False' with 'barcode.get()' and it raised an error:

---

```
barcode_writer = ImageWriter()

ean = barcode.get('code39', "Testing-One-two-1-2",barcode_writer,  add_checksum=False)
```

> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 barcode_writer = ImageWriter()
>   ----> 2 ean = barcode.get('code39', "Testing-One-two-1-2",barcode_writer,  add_checksum=False)
>
> TypeError: get() got an unexpected keyword argument 'add_checksum'

---

So I found on module reference page (https://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/codes.html) that you can specify the type of barcode, using it as a class and then you can provide the paramenter 'add_checksum=False'.

---

```
barcode_writer = ImageWriter()

ean = barcode.codex.Code39( "Testing-One-two-1-2", barcode_writer,  add_checksum=False)

unique_filename = uuid.uuid4()

filename = ean.save(unique_filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

Peter M is right, the extra character is a checksum.  You can omit it by specifying `add_checksum=False`:

```
ean = barcode.get('code39', "Testing-One-two-1-2", barcode_writer, add_checksum=False)
```

ref: http://pythonhosted.org/pyBarcode/barcode.html